# Routers inside routers

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to use routers inside another routers. I have tried

```
  router.get('/foo', require('path to some express router'));
```

and then in 'some express router file'

```
  router.get('/bar', function(req, res){...});
```

The thing is that fist router doesn't strip /foo from url so if i request /foo/bar second router will still look for /foo/bar and /bar wont get called. Is there a way around this other than router.get('/foo/bar'... which is kinda useless as a solution to me.

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this but your syntax is a little off:

In your main file (where `app` is defined):

```
app.use('/foo', require('path to some express router'));
```

And in your router file:

```
router.get('/bar', function(req, res){...});
```

Make sure you export the router object from your router file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router;

router.get('/bar', function(req, res){...});

module.exports = router;
```

**Edit:** to use internationalisation like you suggested, you can provide this `:locale` subsitution at your mount point:

```
app.use('/:locale', require('path to some express router'));
```

Then, in your endpoints, you can call `req.param('locale')`. You can use unlimited combinations of `.use` and `.[verb]` in your applications.

Comment: I know i can use that... thing is I am wondering if it is possible to go one layer more layer down. in my app.js i have app.use('/', require(route to fist router /foo). The reason im asking this is that i use /xx/ for internationalization and I was wondering if it would be possible to use routers to strip those language codes, and then still use routers inside to order my app, without using regExp in every route.